# Réfléchir/raisonner nos actions (sans le "à")

Tags: grammaire

> Nous ne devons pas agir sous l'impulsion, nous devons réfléchir nos
>   actions / raisonner nos actions

Est-ce que cette phrase est correcte ?

Mettre un "à" après réfléchir/raisonner semble moins agréable et attire moins l'oeil (ça fait moins phrase-choc)

Et (juste une impression) le "à" semble aussi un peu changer le sens : ça semble plus mettre l'emphase sur le moment qui suit l'action, quand l'action est déjà faite. La phrase doit focaliser sur le fait de réfléchir en temps réel ("il faut constamment réfléchir ses actions" et non pas les faire impulsivement).

Comment: *Réfléchir nos actions* ? Hmmm... tu veux dire... nous les reprendre dans la figure ? **Attention!** Réfléchir utilisé en transitif direct n'a pas le même sens qu'utilisé en transitif indirect.

Comment: Et quant à *raisonner nos actions*... c'est pas bien mieux. Tu veux dire... *leur expliquer que c'est pas bien ce qu'elles font ?*

Comment: Merci ! Effectivement ça semble confusant de ne pas mettre le "à".

Comment: A more idiomatic way to express your idea is: "Il ne faut pas agir ***sur un coup de tête***". En fait, il suffit de la locution "sur un coup de tête" pour évoquer une ***action irréfléchie***, ce qui rend superflue la proposition "nous devons réfléchir nos actions". :)

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens : Ta suggestion traduit effectivement bien mieux la première partie de la phrase de l'OP. (*Nous ne devons pas agir sous l'impulsion*). Mais **la première partie seulement**. Si, comme je le comprends il faut développer, argumenter... Alors... la question de l'OP se pose vraiment.

Comment: « Les miroirs feraient bien de *réfléchir* un peu plus avant de renvoyer les images. » Jean Cocteau qui ne *résonnait* pas comme un tambour :-) — « Nous ne devons pas agir sous l'impulsion nous devons ***réfléchir / penser / cogiter / gamberger / méditer*** nos actions.

Answer (score 4):

Il n'est pas question ici d'*agréable à l’œil* et encore moins d'*emphase*. Il est question de sens.

**Réfléchir** n'a pas le même sens utilisé en transitif direct (réfléchir + COD) qu'en transitif indirect (réfléchir + COI).

Le sens que tu sembles ici vouloir suggérer est celui du transitif indirect => **réfléchir à** ! Period!

**Raisonner**, utilisé transitivement comme tu le fais dans ton exemple signifie amener le COD à entendre raison. Or c'est un peu difficile pour une action que d'entendre raison.

Tu peux alors vouloir l'utiliser pronominalement. Car... le sujet lui... il sait faire ça : *on doit **se** raisonner* (avant d'agir)

Answer (score 0):

**I** On ne considère d'abord que « réfléchir ».

Nous ne devons pas agir sous l'impulsion, nous devons peser le pour et le contre de nos actions.

Cet usage est couvert par la définition suivante du TLFi.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9fl%C3%A9chir)) 1. Examiner longuement.
> ♦︎  Attends!... T'as pas tout réfléchi?... Reste là! T'as encore cinq minutes! (Céline, Mort à crédit,1936, p. 694).
> Rem. On ne relève que qq. ex. att. de cet empl. trans. dir. noté comme incorrect par la plupart des grammaires et des dict.
> − Loc. ♦︎ Tout bien réfléchi; c'est tout réfléchi. Après avoir tout bien examiné. C'est tout réfléchi, je ne me marie pas, ça n'est pas mon idée (Loti, Pêch. Isl.,1886, p. 103)
> ♦︎ − Vous allez, une fois encore, m'offrir votre démission. Et vous croyez que cela suffit? Non, Monsieur Salavin. Non! Tout bien réfléchi, je vous garde. Vous m'entendez? Vous me comprenez? Je vous garde. Autrement dit, je ne vous lâche pas. Vous êtes un homme dangereux. Duhamel, Journal Salav., 1927, p. 129.

L'idée que « mettre un « à » après « réfléchir/raisonner » serait moins agréable et attirerait moins l'oeil (ça fait moins phrase-choc) » est subjective, elle n'a aucune réalité.

Le sens change, mais c'est seulement, comme cela se lit dans la définition, qu'au lieu d'une réflexion quelconque elle doit être plus sérieuse (longue).

Non, au contraire, l'emphase n'est pas mise sur le moment qui suit l'action mais plutôt sur un moment qui précède, possiblement juste avant l'action (ce que « en tempq réel » voudrait exprimer, mais en temps réel signifie « immédiatement » ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_temps_r%C3%A9el)))

On voit dans la définition qu'il n'existe que quelque cas attestés, ceci étant vrai pour ce qui est de l'emploi général . Ce n'est pas le cas en ce qui concerne les locutions suivantes.

- Tout bien réfléchi, c'est tout réfléchi ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tout+bien+r%C3%A9fl%C3%A9chi%2Cc%27est+tout+r%C3%A9fl%C3%A9chi&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctout%20bien%20r%C3%A9fl%C3%A9chi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cc%27est%20tout%20r%C3%A9fl%C3%A9chi%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctout%20bien%20r%C3%A9fl%C3%A9chi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cc%27est%20tout%20r%C3%A9fl%C3%A9chi%3B%2Cc0))

**II** Le verbe « raisonner » ne suit pas les même principes, il n'est pas tout à fait un synonyme de « réfléchir »,  son sens concerne plus la justification logique des choses que leur simple possibilité.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/raisonner)) **II.** − Empl. trans.
> **A.** − Raisonner qqc.
> **1.** Expliquer les causes d'un événement pour en avoir une vue juste; analyser la motivation d'un comportement, d'une attitude, les motifs d'une action pour en avoir la maîtrise ou un meilleur contrôle. Synon. analyser, étudier.
> ♦︎ Raisonner sa conduite; raisonner ses impulsions, ses sentiments, ses choix; raisonner sa peur, sa colère.
> ♦︎ Vous avez une si grande habitude du commerce que vous savez raisonner vos entreprises, vous êtes un malin (Balzac, C. Birotteau, 1837, p. 161).
> ♦︎ Je vous donne mon impression naïve sans la raisonner (Du Camp, Hollande, 1859, p. 70).
> ♦︎ Seuls capables [les Bien-pensants] de raisonner la guerre [de 1914], c'est-à-dire d'en nommer les causes, d'en dénoncer les auteurs, et d'en justifier les buts (Bernanos, Gde peur, 1931, p. 420):

La construction avec « à » n'existe pas et la construction transitive (sans « à ») est courante.

Comment: If you want to teach someone something, the best way is always the simplest. By quoting so much material, you make the reader dizzy. Who cares about all that? The main point is about explaining why to think about needs à in Fench.

Comment: @Lambie I wouldn't mind to dispatch my answers as  as you do yours, if by so doing I would only be able  to treat  properly the whole question, but things are not always simple. A complex question, which on the top of being complex shows several misconceptions on the part of the OP requires an answer that is thourough and considers each one of those errors of thinking.  There can be too many examples only for readers who are not too interested (the references give such lists of examples, why not me?): the understanding of a language lies in the analysis of a lot of examples of its use.

Comment: A verb changing its meaning with a preposition is not complicated. You just need to give one example of each. Not 10. [I wouldn't mind dispatch**ing***]

Comment: @Lambie You are right, there is no "to" construction for "mind". Thanks for telling.  I wish there was a way to edit comments ; a lot of them are worth reading. // It is not just one verb, it's two, and "raisonner" is not used with "à" at all. You have to deal with that, among other things. // Who's forcing you to read all the examples, there is nothing easier than to skip them after the first one.

Comment: Whatever, it is, one example with a meaning for each is enough. I am talking here about methodology. [[There were two verbs. raisonner and réfléchir.  The meaning of réfléchir changes with à and without à.]] [[That's the kind of structure you might use.]]